# Distcp retry error when i use aws credentials

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs

I am trying to push some logs files from hdfs to s3 bucket

I am using the distcp command for this, But it keeps on trying for a long time, Please help me troubleshoot it.

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop distcp -Dfs.s3a.access.key="xxxxxxxxxx" -Dfs.s3a.secret.key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" hdfs://prod1/data/exchange/inventory_snapshot/20160610 s3a://test-inventory-snapshot/test/

18/11/27 15:01:41 INFO tools.DistCp: Input Options: DistCpOptions{atomicCommit=false, syncFolder=false, deleteMissing=false, ignoreFailures=false, maxMaps=20, sslConfigurationFile='null', copyStrategy='uniformsize', sourceFileListing=null, sourcePaths=[hdfs://prod1/data/exchange/inventory_snapshot/20160610], targetPath=s3a://test-inventory-snapshot/test, targetPathExists=true, preserveRawXattrs=false}
18/11/27 15:01:41 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at xxxx.xxxx.com/xx.xx.xx.x:8032
18/11/27 15:01:47 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at xxxx.xxxx.com/xx.xx.xx.x:8032
18/11/27 15:01:48 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: xxxx.xxxx.com/xx.xx.xx.x:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=50, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
18/11/27 15:01:49 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: xxxx.xxxx.com/xx.xx.xx.x:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=50, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
18/11/27 15:01:50 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: xxxx.xxxx.com/xx.xx.xx.x. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=50, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
18/11/27 15:01:51 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: xxxx.xxxx.com/xx.xx.xx.x:8032. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=50, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
18/11/27 15:01:52 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: xxxx.xxxx.com/xx.xx.xx.x:8032. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=50, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

when i try to do a ls command it works , something wrong with the way i passing my aws credentials,

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -ls hdfs://prod1/data/exchange/inventory_snapshot/20160610
Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x   - user hdfs          0 2016-06-10 12:30 hdfs://prod1/data/exchange/inventory_snapshot/20160610/.metadata

 hadoop version
Hadoop 2.7.1.2.3.2.0-2950
Subversion git@github.com:hortonworks/hadoop.git -r 5cc60e0003e33aa98205f18bccaeaf36cb193c1c
Compiled by jenkins on 2015-09-30T18:08Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 69a3bf8c667267c2c252a54fbbf23d
This command was run using /usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/hadoop/lib/hadoop-common-2.7.1.2.3.2.0-2950.jar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Connecting to ResourceManager at xxxx.xxxx.com/xx.xx.xx.x:8032

Looks like you can't reach your YARN ResourceManager from the host you are trying to run a distcp job. The "hadoop fs -ls" works because it doesn't involve YARN.

There are multiple reasons why this could happen. Check if ResourceManager is indeed running on the node xxxx.xxxx.com/xx.xx.xx.x:8032, check if you can reach that host/port. Try running some other MapReduce job (e.g. Pi from hadoop-examples).